What are the "help suit" game try methods?
You open one of a major. Partner raises you to two, showing support with 6-10 high card points. You are a rebidder with an intermediate hand, 15-17 high card points. Opposite an average of "eight" points, you have enough to try for game, but not enough to insist on it as you would with an 18-count.
So you rebid three of a lower ranking suit (usually a minor, but even hearts if your suit is spades) as a "help suit" try to see if there is "something extra" to propel you to game.
In the version I was taught, a three level bid in a new suit shows side suit controls, typically a king or ace, with 3-4 cards in the suit, and a potential for a double fit and several side suit tricks. Let's say a partnership has a double fit of two eight card suits and 17-18 high card points. That leaves ten cards in two more suits, hopefully divided 2-3 opposite 3-2, that is, four losers counting ruffing values. But there will be an ace or king left over (22 minus 18) to reduce the losers to three.
Here's where I am confused. Many players in my club use what I call a "short" help suit convention. Most of the time, this happens in the context of an "implied" raise (not an actual one), such as a Jacoby 2NT over one of a major. Under these circumstances, a bid of a new suit at the three level shows a singleton or void. The idea is to identify (cross) ruffing values that will allow a game to be made with 22-23 high card points. There's even a third version in use at my club, where the three level side suit bid shows controls: either a singleton or void, an ace, or a KQ combo.
Any system is subject to partnership agreement. But which (or all) of these systems is in general use and how do they work? In any case, have I confused any alleged system with something else?

After 1M-2M, I'm almost always making my decision as to whether to pass, invite, or bid game based on losing trick count, not high card points.

@AlexanderWoo: And my comments about points refer to their "efficiency" in generating a good losing trick count. My experience is that 21-22 high card points is enough for game if you have two suits under complete control, a side stopper in a third suit, and enough "shortness" in your two weak suits, or possibly three suits well controlled and shortness in the fourth. The reason you need 24-26 is if you have "wasted values. In many hands of the latter sort, you can through out one or two of your worst honors to get down to 21-22 without changing the result.

I should capitalize Losing Trick Count - this is actually a formal method of hand evaluation.  In a suit with 3 or more cards, you have one loser for every one of A/K/Q you don't have; in a suit with 2 cards, you have on loser for every one of A/K you don't have; a singleton is a loser if it's not the A.  Over 1M-2M, hands with 5 losers force game, hands with 6 losers invite, and hands with 7 or more losers pass.

My sense is that the most common agreement in the US is "help suit" game tries. In help suit game tries, you name a suit in which you could use some help; usually your suit is something like Kxx or Axx, and partner will be able to help with some honors or else shortness to ruff losers. Partner is generally expected to sign off with a bad 7 or worse, go with a good 9 or better, and with an intermediate hand to look at the named suit and decide if they have help. Without help, they might name another suit below 3 of your major in which they do have help, in case help in that suit is good for your hand. This convention is described in more detail in many places accessible through your favorite search engine.
Alternatives to the help suit game try include the natural game try (name a suit with length in search of a double fit) and the short suit game try (name a suit with shortness to help partner identify a hand without wasted values). There are also more exotic methods, like two-way game tries (these allow you to make either a long-suit or a short-suit game try, depending on what is suitable for your hand).

Accurate, but I would argue the "if minimum, stop, maximum go" part.  As our local expert said to my partner once, after 3H+1, "I didn't ask if you had extras, I asked if you had help in diamonds."

I suppose either way is playable, but I think "if minimum, stop, maximum go" is more accurate more often, unless you have a way to more narrowly limit the response range. After 1H-2H-3D, if you could hold AKxx QTx xx Jxxx or QJxx QTx xx Jxxx, it seems to me that the first hand is often two tricks better than the second, and must be enough to go even without diamond help.

+1 for giving the IMHO crucial statement. The point of a short suit trial is not to check for the possibility of a cross ruff (as the OP indicated). Instead, it is about diagnosing wasted strength opposite a singleton.

I think you’d just describe game tries broadly, as a shape-based invite.
As Alexander says ~6 losers, and with a shapely hand. ( With 17+ HCP you can make a strength-based invite in NT or 3 of your suit). So probably less points but with useful shape but there is a lot of overlap. The shape shown is  down to specific partnership agreement.
Some find short suit trials most useful (I dont). Thats akin to making an invitational splinter (and alertable since not a natural suit).
Some still play long suit trials, a weak suit with 3+ sure losers in the suit ( can you cover some losers partner?).
In modern Acol the trial simply shows 5 cards in the 1st suit bid and invitational strength ( in contrast to 4 cards for 2NT or 6 card with 3X).
GIB seems to use a modern and typical broad Help try, promising just 3 cards including Q+, but not denying more strength in the suit though inevitably short elsewhere. (So partner, you work out how your hand can fit with mine to reduce your 9 losers to 8. Can you cover or ruff my losers or make a double fit? etc.)
Any shape agreement is theoretically possible though typically longer or shorter than average shape which is useful to know. Control bids are generally kept for slam try situations rather than game tries (such as after a jump raise 1H 3H 3S)
(NB: And, one shouldn’t confuse game tries with the strong invite after opponents compete in another suit 1H 2H [2S] 3D, which is a different context)
